# Why different appliances draw different current inspite of equal voltage?

Tags: voltage, power, current

Power of a device can be calculated by formula \$P = VI\$, means that if voltage provided to two devices is same but their power is different, it means that high power device is drawing more current according to formula \$P=VI\$. But we also know that current \$I\$ is directly proportional to voltage \$V\$ from ohm law \$V = IR\$.

So why two different devices with different power ratings draw different current even though they have same value of voltage?

Comment: Um... different R or impedance really

Comment: Because they have different Rs

Comment: Just because *I* is proportional to *V* doesn't mean that *I* is equal to *V*

Comment: household circuits are wired in parallel so each appliance can draw a different amount of current while maintaining the same voltage

Answer (score 1):

Consider those huge incandescent bulbs that lit your highschool football field. They ran on 117VAC but used many many amps. Compare those to that tiny bulb in your hallway: only 4 watts but its 10X or 100X brighter than a nightlite.

Its resistance: I = V/R            The voltage across an appliance's innards places an electric field across the motors and solenoids (they go 'click') and heaters and bulbs. The electric field is fixed by the power company's generators and transformers. What varies is what you have plugged into the wall: that appliance.

Answer (score 1):

\$P = IV\$

\$V = IR\$  so \$I = V/R\$

Therefore

\$P = V^2/R\$

Since \$V\$ remains the same, For \$P\$ to change \$R\$ must also change.

at \$110Vac\$

a \$100W\$ light-bulb will have an impedance of \$120\:\Omega\$

a \$60W\$ light-bulb will have an impedance  of \$202\:\Omega\$

As an analogy, why does a bucket full of water empty faster with a bigger hole in the bottom?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one last thing. Going by your explanation, i can say that a light or small load (ceiling fan) pose high resistance to current than a heavy load (Air conditioner)?